# Check if user had autologin & if so, logout

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

With Wordpress, I'm trying to create a function which autologins users, but upon visiting certain pages also performs an autologout if the initial login was obtained via autologin.

I've written the following code but I guess my boolean check for the autologin boolean does not work.

```
/* AUTO LOGIN / LOGOUT */
function autologinout() {
    global $wp;

    // Autologin
    if( isset($_GET['username']) ) {
        $user = get_user_by('login', $_GET['username']);

        // Redirect URL //
        if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            if ( in_array( 'customer', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
                wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
                wp_redirect( '/lovelists/toon-lovelist/' );
                $autologin = true;
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    // Autologout
    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $autologin = true  && ( $path == '/lovelists/maak-lovelist/' || $path == '/lovelists/login/' ) ) {
        wp_clear_auth_cookie(); // so you don't get the cache error
        wp_logout(); // this will logout user
        $autologin = false;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'autologinout' );
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So if someone had url parameter `?username=admin` would it just log them in as admin?

Comment: @HowardE Only customer roles can use autologin, hence the check on the user role.